# undefined reference to `test::setTest(int)'

Tags: c++

When I compile this code  , I have 2 error  "undefined reference to test::setTest(int)" and "undefined reference to test::getTest()". I don't know what's going wrong and I am using g++ compiler in arch linux:

test.h

```
class test{
    int i;
    public :
    void setTest(int);
    int getTest();

  };
```

test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"test.h"

    void test :: setTest(int x){
          i = x;
}
    int test :: getTest(){
        return i;
}
```

mainTest.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"test.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    test t;
    t.setTest(5);
    cout<< "the value of i is : "<<t.getTest();

}
```

Comment: How do you build? You do build with *both* source files (or object files)?

Comment: First i build mainTest.cpp  and get the 2 error and then build test.cpp but error again

Comment: Have you *tried* passing both source files as arguments when building? There are probably tens of thousands of examples all over the Internet (including many here) that tells you how to build programs using multiple source files, just using plain GCC.

Comment: Try to compile both files altogether: `g++ mainTest.cpp test.cpp -o mainTest ` , then run `./mainTest`

Comment: yes ,i compile both of them  altogether and it's worked    
,tnx

Answer (score 1):

You are not compiling both files together, so the output executable does not have references to the class's methods, just on your terminal do:

```
g++ mainTest.cpp test.cpp -o mainTest
```

Then run it as :

```
./mainTest
```